# “Big Fish & Begonia” 大鱼海棠

Tags: translation, idioms, movies

I just saw [the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Fish_%26_Begonia), and I can’t understand why it has this title.

First of all, **A whale is not a fish!**  Is the word translated as “fish” used for all swimming animals?  Even if that’s the case, any idea why the movie producers would use a patently incorrect translation?

And a [begonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia) is a small herbaceous plant, that in no way resembles a big tree.  I think the big flowering tree is what the title is supposed to refer to, as one of the items on the Blu-Ray (a supplemental feature or a song; I don’t recall) gave it as *Big Fish and Chinese Blooming Crabapple*.  I’ve tentatively identified it as *Malus spectabilis*.  So, what’s all the talk about begonias?

Comment: A whale is a fish in many languages, because it looks like a fish and swims like a fish. For example: Chinese 鯨**魚**, Vietnamese **cá** voi, Malay **ikan** paus. In Thai too AFAIK. Even in English we have jelly**fish** and star**fish**...

Answer (score 2):

lost in translation lah :(

according to wiki: the main actress is a fairy in charge of begonia (掌管海棠花)

the main actor, he change into "鯤" a legendary big marine creature, its body is more than several thousand chinese miles long (鯤之大・不知其幾千里也).

"big fish" is a good enough name for such marine creature.

anyway, it's an anime for children, need to have a simple, easy to comprehend name, for both the local & foreign kids.

have fun :)

Comment: I wonder if that’s a pun or wordplay?  Google shows that 鯤 can mean "sea monster" or "young of fishes",fry,whitebait.  The soul turned into a tiny baby Red Dolphin, and would grow into a giant.

Comment: i don't think so: http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000004676 the second explanation :)

Comment: I like the "lah"

Comment: What does “I don't think so” refer to?

Comment: it refers to “a pun or wordplay”